# 'KMeans' object has no attribute '_n_threads'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Keep getting this error and I suspect it is related to the version difference between the sklearn, but I am not sure. 
Also I have tried to update the sklearn version, **but I cannot install past 0.22 version in my Jupiter notebook**

---

#### Pickle and fit with sklearn version 0.22 on a Jupyter notebook

Running on AWS Sagemaker

```py
model = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
model.fit(df[:train])

centroids = model.cluster_centers_
centroids_label = model.labels_

#Save model
model_file_name = 'model-name-v1.pkl'
model_pkl = open(model_file_name, 'wb')
pickle.dump(model, model_pkl)
model_pkl.close()
saved_model_pkl = open(model_file_name, 'rb')

object = s3.Object(bucket_name, 'models/{}'.format(model_file_name))
object.put(Body=saved_model_pkl)
```

---

#### Unpickle and predict with sklearn version 0.23

This is the code that unpickle the model from an S3 bucket, this is running on AWS lambda:

```py
import json
import os
import pickle


def lambda_handler(event, context):
        parameter_for_evaluation = [
           # features
        ]
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key='models/{}'.format(model_file_name))
        body = response['Body'].read()
        model = pickle.loads(body)
        result = model.predict([parameter_for_evaluation]).tolist()[0]
        print("model result: ", result)
```

And this is the error: in my AWS lambda when try to `predict`

```
'KMeans' object has no attribute '_n_threads': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 58, in lambda_handler
    result = model.predict([parameter_for_evaluation]).tolist()[0]
  File "/var/task/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py", line 1188, in predict
    self.cluster_centers_, self._n_threads)[0]
AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute '_n_threads'
```

There are other warnings in my Cloudwatch logs that might be relevant, however they appeared also before when the error was not happening

```
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k

/var/task/joblib/_multiprocessing_helpers.py:45: UserWarning: [Errno 38] Function not implemented.  joblib will operate in serial mode

warnings.warn('%s. joblib will operate in serial mode' % (e,))

/var/task/sklearn/base.py:334: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator KMeans from version 0.22.1 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
```

---

**This error is not happening if I do the same operation in the same Jupiter notebook**

---

### This is what I have tried to install sklearn 0.23.1

```
# Nothing changed
!conda update sklearn

# Error cannot find pip3
!python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade sklearn

# From the logs is installing 0.22
!pip install sklearn --upgrade


!conda install scikit-learn -y

# Stuck forever at: Solving environment
!conda config --append channels conda-forge
!conda install scikit-learn=0.23.1
```

Comment: You have written the answer here already `/var/task/sklearn/base.py:334: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator KMeans from version 0.22.1 when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.`. It is heavily recommended to use the exact same version of the libraries in the runtime environment as in the build.

Comment: @RichardNemeth thanks, it has always worked though, just today it started to give me this error. 
But now that I know it for sure I will try to match the versions.

But it looks like I cannot update it. I have tried many things, but the version is still stuck at 0.22

Comment: @Madeo have you got the solution?

Comment: @sa_n__u yes, as Richard said the versions should be the same. Downgrading sklearn to 0.22 has worked. Unfortunately I could not upgrade it in the Sagemaker jupiter notebook

Answer (score 1):

Some of my students ran into the same error when accessing the internals of an KMeans object:

```
kmeans2 = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)  
kmeans2.cluster_centers_ = clusters
```

In this scenario the problem could be worked around by running KMeans with a small subset of the original data.

```
kmeans2 = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters).fit(df[:smallnumber])
kmeans2.cluster_centers_ = clusters
```

Where `clusters` is a reordered set of clusters from another KMeans instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to versioning of `scikit-learn`, the models were trained with an older version. If you can't downgrade the version of `scikit-learn` you can use the following code to allow predictions with your KMeans model.

```py
import pickle
from sklearn.utils._openmp_helpers import _openmp_effective_n_threads

# Load the model
model = pickle.loads(body)
model._n_threads = _openmp_effective_n_threads()

result = model.predict([parameter_for_evaluation]).tolist()[0]
```

the key is in this import: `from sklearn.utils._openmp_helpers import _openmp_effective_n_threads`

Answer (score -1):

Retraining the model with latest package versions should solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Harsh Chindarker.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your answer is a little light - could you expand on it a bit.  Why would retraining the model help, for example.